# Can the user generate instantly a notification bar on Stack Exchange sites (content is irrelevant) without relying on any other variables?

Tags: discussion, notifications

Can the user generate instantly a notification bar on Stack Exchange sites (content is irrelevant) without relying on any other variables? It would ordinarily appear when a certain state is reached; e. g., when state changes to Student: "Asked first question with score of 1 or more".

Can the notifications appearing at the top be checked via a live feed?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: You want to generate a notification showing up for yourself?

Comment: perhaps instead of meaningless character count filler you could explain yourself? While you clearly know what it is you're trying to find out, the rest of us don't. "Yes" is not a super helpful response. An example, or a discussion of motivation, might lead to clarity for everyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things you can do that will cause an instant notification. For example, you can delete a downvoted question or answer, causing a positive score increase that you will be instantly notified of. You can take an action that directly leads to a badge (some badges are caused by the actions of others or are awarded by batch jobs that run every so often.) Badges caused by your own actions appear to be more than half the [available badges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) - too many to list here.

There is nothing you can do to turn these on or off, however - all positive rep changes generate notifications, badges generate notifications either always, or for all users under a certain rep (experienced users apparently can't be bothered with some badge notifications), and comments directed at you, new answers to your question etc happen whether you want them to or not. You can't suppress them and you can't trigger them either.

Is this what you're asking? It's not super clear.

Comment: Yes, that was what I was asking. Thank you for answering.
My question was specifically aimed at determining whether there was a fast method to generate a notification bar that does not have a large number of dependencies and works regardless of the user's parameters. For instance, to get a notification bar I could activate "First rollback," but then this action, while having a relatively small number of dependencies, restricts the state of the user with which it will work; i. e., it requires the absence of prior rollbacks.